# My reputation graph is messed up.

Tags: bug, reputation, meta, reputation-graph

See here:

https://stackapps.com/users/18?tab=reputationhistory#tab-top

Go to my rep graph and notice that it only shows about 350 points...

Where's my other 4100?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think this is not specific to Stack Apps, All the reputation graph on Trilogy site don't show bonus points. For your case, 100 is from Account Associations, 4000 is from Api Evangelist badge bonus point.

But I hope they could add those bonus info to reputation-graph as well.